# How to display long text across the lines without lossing any text at the end of thee lines

Tags: android, textview

Which property of the `TextView` I should use when I want my long text to be splitted across the next line. For an example, I ahve a `TextView` that displays a path of an image and the path is long and it consumes two lines, and when displayed on its respective `TextView` the text gets splitted across the second line but with some text in the first line is missing at the end. I have checked the property of `android:ellipsize` but it is not what I need.

TextView_xml

```
<TextView 
   android:id="@+id/reportImgPathValue"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried a combination of  
android:maxLines="2" and 
android:ellipsize="end"?

Comment: @tritop no, i would try and inform

Comment: post your `TextView` xml.

Comment: @HamidShatu please see the posted textview

Comment: @tritop after testing, no it is became one line only?

Comment: android:maxLines="2" try this one i think it's working. and check your code by fault declare android:singleLine="true".

Comment: Yup, try maxlines="2" only without ellipsize. If it still doesn't work, make sure there is enough space for 2 lines. Also try minLines instead of maxLines and see what happens. If there are no 2 lines with minLines="2" the problem might me the surounding layout.

Comment: @tritop unfortunately it does not work either.

Comment: I solved it by making the `marquee text`

Comment: can I make this as a solution for my question?

Comment: Post it as answer, explain what you did to solve the question, mark your post as solution after you posted it by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the "line" property like the ones below should do the trick:

android:minLines - Makes the TextView be at least this many lines tall.

android:lines - Makes the TextView be exactly this many lines tall.